# Odd cp behavior in bash script

Tags: bash, unix, aix

I have a bash script that is copying some files, but it doesn't seem to be working properly. A side note is that there are no matching files in the source directory. But the point of the script is to copy files *if* there are files to copy.

A basic snippet of what I'm trying to do:

```
source_loc=/u01
target_log=/u02
/usr/bin/cp "$source_loc"/dir/*file* "$target_loc"/dir/
```

Results in

```
Usage: cp [-fhipHILPU][-d|-e] [-r|-R] [-E{force|ignore|warn}] [--] src target
or: cp [-fhipHILPU] [-d|-e] [-r|-R] [-E{force|ignore|warn}] [--] src1 ... srcN directory
```

If I add set -x to my script, I get this...

```
+ /usr/bin/cp /u02/dir/
Usage: cp [-fhipHILPU][-d|-e] [-r|-R] [-E{force|ignore|warn}] [--] src target
or: cp [-fhipHILPU] [-d|-e] [-r|-R] [-E{force|ignore|warn}] [--] src1 ... srcN directory
 + set +x
```

The EXTRA peculiar thing about this is that if I **re-run** the script without changing anything, I get this as my output:

```
cp: /u01/dir/*file*: No such file or directory
```

Now I haven't tested this script with matching files in the source (I will be very shortly) but I want to make sure I'm not missing something. I don't care about getting an error, I just want to be sure I get the correct error (i.e. no such file or directory).

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: We await your with-matching-files test.

Comment: Great. Thank you. Unfortunately the actual script takes some time to run, so it may be a bit. I am testing. Anything about the above flat out wrong?

Comment: You should be using `find`? `find $source_loc/dir/ -type f -exec cp {} $target_loc/dir/ \;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find` as suggested by @elliotfrisch:

```
find "$source_dir/dir" -type f -name "*file*" -maxdepth 1 -exec cp {} "$target_loc/dir" \;
```

Alternatively, in Bash, you can capture the glob results into an array and invoke `cp` when the array is not empty:

```
shop -s nullglob # glob expands to nothing if there are no matching files
files=("$source_loc/dir/"*file*)
((${#files[@]} > 0)) && cp "${files[@]}" "$target_loc"/dir/
```

Comment: So obviously there was a bug in my code. I'm marking @codeforester's answer as correct because they pointed me in the direction. So before I attempt this copy, there is a function that executes. And in this function I set shop -s nullglob. And I try to unset it at the end of the function, but I had a typo. The trick is this function only gets executed if it wasn't previously executed (hence why subsequent runs were returning expected error). I updated my code to do shop -u nullglob and I get the expected no such file or directory message. Note that there were no issues when there was a match